# jquery and jquery.mobile mixing breaks form

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, form-submit

I try to use jquery and jquery.mobile libraries in the same code:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>`

But it breaks a submit form, with the following error code, when pressing submit button:

"Uncaught TypeError: this.hash is not a function       jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:4"

The weird thing is that I don't have any jquery function tied to a submit event.

I tried declaring a global

var jQuery = $.noConflict(true);

and then using jQuery instead of $ in the code, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By default jquery mobile sends forms by ajax. So this behaviour had to be changed:

```
<form data-ajax="false">
...
</form>
```